# How to set a background image to full screen width in Wordpress Elementor

Tags: html, css, elementor

EDIT: solved! Check the comments, cheers Dev!

---

On my website's homepage I want to insert a background image that fits the full screen width. I'm using WordPress and Elementor to do this.

I've tried many setups but I'm unable to fill the full screen width, while keeping the correct image height so the ratios stay correct.

A part of the right side of the image was cut off.

Code I used:

```
<div id="kunstplein1920"></div>

#kunstplein1920 {
background: url(imageURLhere);
background-repeat: no-repeat center fixed;
background-size: cover;
min-width: 1920px;
min-height: 603px;}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks. :)

Cheers,

Joris

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding

`width: 100%`?

should be working

Comment: If I add "width: 100%" nothing changes. If I leave out "min-height: 603px;" then nothing is shown. After adding "width: 100%" and "height: 100%" (leaving out min-width and min-height) still nothing is shown. Any ideas on what's going wrong here?

Comment: is this the desired output? https://codepen.io/oskedram/pen/wveogLd

Comment: when not tell me how do you want to have it done

Comment: and i will try to find out why it does not work

Comment: Thanks for your help Dev! Still a part of the image is cut off, compare it to the image itself: https://kunstkring.brunsham.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/samenstelling_1920x603_lower.jpg

Comment: Hi @Joris sorry for taking longer to respond, had work to do; i found this:

Comment: try using "aspect-ratio: auto 1296 / 407;". Heres the codepen: https://codepen.io/oskedram/pen/wveogLd

Comment: to make it responsive we wont be using width: 100% since it is messing up our backround so i would recommend using "@media screen" Heres a tutorial when youre not familiar with it: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: @Joris theres another way by not setting the image as backround for your div in css, and putting it inside the div in html ---> this way allows us to use "width: 100%" and is making the image responsive at all times ;) heres a codepen:  https://codepen.io/oskedram/pen/bGRBgPR

Comment: thanks so much for looking into this! The last thing you mentioned, inserting the image in HTML instead of using it as a background image, that did the trick. I ended up making an image map using an online free tool (https://www.image-map.net/) and inserted the image like seen in this Codepen: https://codepen.io/Valoop/pen/powWvxy

Comment: Cheeers! And I have an even better version now, a fully responsive image map following the steps mentioned here: https://torquemag.io/2021/03/how-to-create-a-wordpress-image-map-and-why-you-should/

End result (V1 of the new home page): https://kunstkring.brunsham.nl/home-2-0/

Comment: nice! Cool looking site